# Is "Call me whenever possible" correct?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

One of my colleague asked me that "What time can I call you". I need to answer him.

Is this correct? If not please suggest the correction(s).

Comment: Can you give a little more information? Context may be important here.

Comment: @mike. Thanks for the fast respond. I have added more information. Please read it again and ask me if you need little more context.

Comment: It's *correct* but not really idiomatic.  A more common expression is "call (me) whenever it's convenient (for you)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it is grammatically correct.

The longer answer is that it sounds a little formal, and depending on the situation, there may be better alternatives.

If there's an element of the phone call being urgent or time critical, then you could say

- Call me as soon as you can.
- Call me as soon as possible.
- Call me as soon as you are free.

If it's not urgent, and you just want to convey that you are happy for him or her to call you back, then something like

- Call me whenever you can.
- Call me when you get the chance.
- Call me when you are free.

might be more suitable.

Comment: I believe that "Call me when you get a chance." also correct. Am I right?

Comment: I would think so, yes.